# How to Redirect 301 an old URL http to new URL https on .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have an old URL before that is not https, now that I have applied SSL on my site and I changed a few URLs, my Redirect 301 is not working.

```
Redirect 301 /consultancy/Scoping-and-Specification /custom-systems
```

Above is my code, though I have seen some answers online which leads to something like this;

```
Redirect 301 /consultancy/Scoping-and-Specification https://www.example.com/custom-systems
```

The above code didn't work as well for me, my .htacess is using force https as well. Here is my code.

```
# redirecting all access to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# redirecting all access to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Kindly help me if how to redirect them to https. TIA!